# Best way to get id of state machine but achieve the same functionality

Tags: state

We currently have a state machine that does something similar the following.

```
Switch(state)
{
    Case A:
              DoA();
              state = B;
              break;
    Case B: DoB();
            state = C;
            break;
    Case C: if(condition)
               state = A;// Start from A again
            else
               state = D;
               break;
    .... more states
}
```

As a team we decided to get rid of the state machine and now I am working on making the code as linear as possible. We use c++.

What would be the most elegant way to achieve this? I was thinking about having the code as a single function and call the same function again but I am not happy with calling it recursively.

Any ideas?

Comment: Command pattern, polymorphism